# Repl.it: Package operation failed on Flask, 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, flask, python-poetry, replit

I'm trying to use the Flask library for my bot in repl.it and I keep getting the following error.

```
Replit: Updating package configuration

--> python3 -m poetry add flask
Using version ^2.1.2 for Flask

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies...

  TypeError

  'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

  at venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/repositories/pypi_repository.py:282 in _get_release_info
      278│             cache_version=str(self.CACHE_VERSION),
      279│         )
      280│ 
      281│         try:
    → 282│             version_info = json_data["releases"][version]
      283│         except KeyError:
      284│             version_info = []
      285│ 
      286│         for file_info in version_info:
exit status 1


Replit: Package operation failed.
```

Any help is appreciated

EDIT:
Here is the code of the Flask file I'm trying to run

```
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread

app = Flask('')

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return "hello"

def run():
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8080)

def keep_alive():
    t = Thread(target=run)
    t.start()
```

Comment: When I run it (in Replit) it works fine: `Using version ^2.1.2 for Flask`
`Updating dependencies`
`Resolving dependencies... (2.3s)`
`Writing lock file`
`No dependencies to install or update`

Comment: Just to add, I've seen multiple YT videos on similar topic but no one is having an issue installing Flask and I can't point out the reason

Comment: having the same issue on Quart

Comment: @Seiden could you link the YT videos about it?

Comment: @DankCoder I was following [this video, timestamp included](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SPTfmiYiuok&t=3522)

Comment: @Seiden managed to fix it, go to repl.it's shell and type `pip uninstall poetry`. once that's done do, `pip install poetry`. apparently it had to do with repl using an older version of it